# How to select from a list of "or" - dependencies?

Tags: apt, software-installation, dependencies

Example: https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/php7.2

`php` package depends on one of:

- `libapache2-mod-php7.2`
- `php7.2-fpm`
- `php7.2-cgi`

Running `sudo apt install php` always installs the first of these dependencies, unless one of the others has been installed already. Even running `sudo apt install php php-cli` installs the first dependency.

How can I select e.g. `php-cgi` in one go ?

So instead of

```
sudo apt install php-cgi && sudo apt install php
```

I want something like

```
sudo apt install --select-dependency php-cgi php
```

---

> Please note that `php` is just an example, I'm looking for a general answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can provide **multiple arguments** to `apt install` to dictate which packages you want to install in one go - this is so automated installation scripts and such as well as users can install **all** the defined packages in a single go rather than trying to do it one by one by one.

The general syntax is this:

```
sudo apt install package1 package2 package3 package4 ...
```

How the various packages behave with this **will vary based on the package and its dependencies**.

But in the case of `php` its its own hell to install because in SOME cases `apt` is stupid when resolving the dependencies, so if you need `php-cli` just install it and only it:

```
sudo apt install php-cli
```

Same behavior for `php-fpm` too or `php-cgi` - just install it, it'll pull in the common dependencies it needs.

Comment: @pLumo Correction: apt is stupid with metapackage deps.  THIS SAID you only need to install `php-cli` to get php CLI interface, it does not need the rest of `php` to work this way.  And as I stated already, **how apt handles this will be entirely dependent on the packages, its dependencies, and any metapackage dependency evils that are involved.**  Since you asked for a "general" solution I gave you a general solution.

Comment: sure, `php-cli` depends on `php`, that is clever ;-)

Comment: @pLumo actually, it doesn't depend on the `php` metapackage at all; see https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/YdMbk8jvrN/ for the dep chain on 18.04 as an example.  It pulls in php7.2-common which is the 'common' php bits common to all PHP drivers.

Comment: `cgi` vs `cli` was a typo-kind of problem of my side. But `sudo apt install php php-cgi` vs `sudo apt install php php7.2-cgi` nailed it. Maybe you can add this information to the answer ... that apt does not resolve dependencies when deciding that...